# Как отключить автоматическое закрытие виртуальной клавиатуры Android?

Tags: android

Есть webView, есть toolbar. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на item toolbar-а виртуальная клавиатура не закрывалась автоматически, а еще лучше чтобы вообще не закрывалась?
Клавиатура прячется именно в тот момент когда я вызываю функцию javascript из webview.

```
case R.id.italic_text:
    mWebMessageCreater.loadUrl("javascript:italicText()");
break;
```

Как то в этот момент не дать клавиатуре закрыться?

Answer (score 2):

Клава должна закрываться при потере фокуса тем элементом разметки, коий её вызвал. Засим, думаю, возможно повесить слушатель изменения фокуса на `WebView` и показывать в нём клавиатуру снова. Возможно будет "мигать", но врядли можно без адЪских костылей такое поведение изменить ибо скрытие клавы при потере фокуса должно быть сильно вмуровано в систему.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам требуется, чтобы клавиатура постоянно присутствовала при открытии определенной активити, то в параметрах этой активити в манифесте пропишите для `windowSoftInputMode` значение `stateAlwaysVisible` - клавиатура всегда будет видима при старте этой активити.

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
   android:name=".SomeActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"       
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >
</activity>
```

Если требуется, чтобы клавиатура появилась по определенному событию и потом уже оставалась постоянно, то при наступлении события выполните следующий код (в манифесте при этом ничего писать не надо):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Для того, чтобы вернуть нормальное (дефолтное) поведение клавиатуры, вызовите этот же код еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот код. `mEditText` это `EditText` где должен отображаться ввод.

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня такой вариант работает.
В Манифесте Активити:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivity"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_my_article"       
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Собственно в методе:

```
case R.id.italic_text:
    mWebMessageCreater.loadUrl("javascript:italicText()");

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(body, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

break;
```

Но как и писал ЮрийСПБ - мигание не исключается и этим методом. Но на шустрых аппаратах это практически незаметно.