# Как поместить элемент перед фоном клавиатуры

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Внутри View поместил TextInput с кнопкой(position:absolute). Инпут для поискового запроса.

```js
<View style={styles.searchContainer}>
  <TextInput
    style={[commonStyles.text.base, styles.searchInput]}
    onChangeText={(text) => props.changeSearch(text)} />
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searchArrowContent}
                      onPress={() => pressSearch()}>
      <Image style={styles.searchArrow}
             source={require('res/img/arrows/arrow-right.png')} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '90%',
    padding: 0,
  }
  searchArrowContent: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  searchArrow: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    marginTop: 4
  },
});
```

Кликаем на инпут, появляется клавиатура. Вводим текст появляется кнопка для перехода к результатам запроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кликнуть в любую область экрана, то клавиатура закроется. Так же, если кликнуть на кнопку, то клавиатура закрывается и для перехода приходится кликать ещё раз по кнопке. 
Вопрос: как поместить кнопку перед фоном клавиатуры, чтобы пользователь при открытой клавиатуре кликнул по кнопке лишь 1 раз?

Comment: Вообще не понятно куда вы что хотите поместить... Но что бы клавиатура не закрывалась, то вам нужно переопределить логику закрытия  клавиатуры, а не помещать непонятно кого, непонятно куда.

Comment: @Valeriy, на картинке сверху красным указана область, в этой области находится галочка >. Мне нужно, чтобы при открытой клавиатуре, когда я нажимаю на эту галочку, происходило действие, которое я повесил на эту галочку. Но при нажатии на неё только лишь закрывается клавиатура, и приходится кликать ещё раз. Я полагаю, что при открытой клавиатуре появляется невидимая область, которая закрывает всё и получается, что я кликаю на эту область. И видимо нужно галочку сделать "ближе" той области, чтобы я кликал на галочку, а не на область(клавиатуры).

Comment: Не совсем так. Вам лучше обработать поведение клавиатуры в не области неё самой. Вы не стой стороны подходите к проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472742/238266